# How to set latitude & longitude in url if it is changing dynamically & to get list view via json?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

How to set latitude & longitude in url if it is changing dynamically & to get list view via json?

This is url example

```
https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=5&km=1&location=true&lat=19.0558306414&long=72.8339840099
```

Here we can see the in the url "lat=19.0558306414&long=72.8339840099" is set on the basis i am getting distance via url .

But right now i have manually fixed in the url with this latitude & longitude value .

But it can be changed when user will move to other location ? Then how to set this in url ? so based on the latitude & longitude would get result after hitting url (json).

Note : from Back end result is coming on the basis of latitude & longitude. distance is calculating on the basis of  latitude & longitude in backend .
How to set dynamically in the url latitude & longitude in this url . Please help me.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // change here url of server api
    private static final String url = "https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=5&km=1&location=true&lat=19.0558306414&long=72.8339840099";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("average_ratings", movie.getAverage_ratings());
                intent.putExtra("full_address", movie.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("image_url", movie.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putExtra("cuisine",movie.getCuisine());
                intent.putExtra("cost",movie.getCost());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Keep patience.Its loading...");

        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                JSONArray

                        restaurantsJSONArray= null;
                try {
                    restaurantsJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                hidePDialog();
                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurantsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj =restaurantsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                        //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                        movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                        movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                        movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                        // movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("full_address"));
                        movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));
                        movie.setDistance( obj.getDouble("distance"));

                        JSONArray    textJSONArray= obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers");

                        for ( int j = 0; j < textJSONArray.length(); j++) {


                            JSONObject txtobj =textJSONArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            //obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(0).getSt‌​ring("text");
                            //movie.settext(obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(j).getSt‌​ring("text"));
                            movie.settext(txtobj .getString("text"));
                        }


                       // movie.settext(obj.getString("text"));
                        movieList.add(movie);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }



}
```

[image]

I am getting this type of list view on the basis of hitting this url

Update code

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // change here url of server api
    // private static final String url = "https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=5&km=1&location=true&lat=19.0558306414&long=72.8339840099";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //update coordinates every 30 seconds
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 1, this);
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("average_ratings", movie.getAverage_ratings());
                intent.putExtra("full_address", movie.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("image_url", movie.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putExtra("cuisine", movie.getCuisine());
                intent.putExtra("cost", movie.getCost());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Keep patience.Its loading...");

        pDialog.show();

    }
    private void loadJson(double latitude, double longitude) {
        url = "https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=5&km=1&location=true&lat=" + latitude + "&long=" + longitude;
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                JSONArray

                        restaurantsJSONArray = null;
                try {
                    restaurantsJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                hidePDialog();
                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurantsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = restaurantsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                        //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                        movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                        movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                        movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                        // movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("full_address"));
                        movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));
                        movie.setDistance(obj.getDouble("distance"));

                        JSONArray textJSONArray = obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers");

                        for (int j = 0; j < textJSONArray.length(); j++) {


                            JSONObject txtobj = textJSONArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            //obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(0).getSt‌​ring("text");
                            //movie.settext(obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(j).getSt‌​ring("text"));
                            movie.settext(txtobj.getString("text"));
                        }


                        // movie.settext(obj.getString("text"));
                        movieList.add(movie);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
       //client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
       // client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this).addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "ListView Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.comida/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "ListView Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.comida/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //whenever location is updated call method that will load JSON
        loadJson(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comida/com.comida.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.comida.ListViewActivity.onStart(ListViewActivity.java:189)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LocationManager class of android to get updated coordinates after a specified interval.
Make your activity implement LocationListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener
```

in your onCreate() method add this code

```
LocationManager  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //update coordinates every 30 seconds
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 1, this);
```

Implement required method of in your Activity

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     //whenever location is updated call method that will load JSON
     loadJson(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
}



@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

loadJson() method

```
private void loadJson(double latitude, double longitude) {
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.clear();
    url = "https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=5&km=1&location=true&lat=" + latitude + "&long=" + longitude;
    JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            JSONArray

                    restaurantsJSONArray = null;
            try {
                restaurantsJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            hidePDialog();
            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < restaurantsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = restaurantsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                    //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                    movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                    movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                    movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                    // movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("full_address"));
                    movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));
                    movie.setDistance(obj.getDouble("distance"));

                    JSONArray textJSONArray = obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers");

                    for (int j = 0; j < textJSONArray.length(); j++) {


                        JSONObject txtobj = textJSONArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        //obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(0).getSt‌​ring("text");
                        //movie.settext(obj.getJSONArray("restaurant_offers").getJSONObject(j).getSt‌​ring("text"));
                        movie.settext(txtobj.getString("text"));
                    }


                    // movie.settext(obj.getString("text"));
                    movieList.add(movie);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Clear you list in CustomListAdapter

```
 public void clear() {
    yourListName.clear();
}
```

Don't forget to add required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: where i have to edit load json in my code after oncreate ()?
Please see update code i have edited separate as per your suggestion .
is this correct ?

Comment: you are right. you need to add loadJson() method after onCreate().

Comment: put this line in onCreate() method                                                          client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

Comment: No, after adding this , list is not coming .
com.google.android.gms signature not valid. THIS IS APPEARING IN LOGCAT

Comment: it is another issue related to your google Api. Did you tried it without implementing Google  library? If not, try once. If still there is error please let me know. If it is related to google api than you should ask it in seperate question.

Comment: please see once again updated code above . client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build(); called on proper place i am in doubt .

Comment: After editing in code I am getting error same as logcat . Please see in the update code i have edited latest update .

Comment: You are still implementing GoogleApiClient. Well check this url https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi  your client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();  is at right place

Comment: You need to update adapter each time you call loadJson() method. See my updated loadJson() and changes in your CustomListAdapter class

Comment: I did same . I am not getting list while i was getting earlier . ONLY  in logcat i am getting this .
08-23 16:44:34.568 8698-8756/com.comida E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae5c4990

Comment: Are you using Marshmallow device for testing? Is your Device Location on when u r testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121613/discussion-between-user6313669-and-saty).